# SSH from Mac to CentOS hangs forever when using a certain domain

Tags: centos7, google-cloud-platform, google-compute-engine, ssh-keys

I've been running a CentOS server on Google Compute for about a year. I SSH in every day without a problem. Suddenly, when I try to ssh in, the command just waits and waits and waits... After experimenting, it appears that I can easily ssh in using all sorts of other ways of referring to the server, but only my main domain causes the problem.

Here's a copy/paste of my command line, with domains and ips changed to protect the innocent. ;)

```
Kenny-iMac:~$ ssh kenny@mymaindomain.com
^C
Kenny-iMac:~$ host mymaindomain.com
mymaindomain.com has address xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx
mymaindomain.com mail is handled by 10 mxa.smtphost.com.
mymaindomain.com mail is handled by 10 mxb.smtphost.com.
Kenny-iMac:~$ ssh kenny@xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx
Last login: Sat Jun  2 18:43:05 2018 from nnn.nnn.nnn.nnn
[kenny@production-frontend-0 ~]$ exit
logout
Connection to xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx closed.
Kenny-iMac:~$ host otherdomainonserver.com
otherdomainonserver.com has address xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx
otherdomainonserver.com mail is handled by 10 mxa.smtphost.com.
otherdomainonserver.com mail is handled by 10 mxb.smtphost.com.
Kenny-iMac:~$ ssh kenny@otherdomainonserver.com
Last login: Sat Jun  2 18:45:20 2018 from nnn.nnn.nnn.nnn
[kenny@production-frontend-0 ~]$ exit
logout
Connection to otherdomainonserver.com closed.
Kenny-iMac:~$
```

I can change the above to include the real domains if that will help diagnose the problem, but figured if it would be better to exclude them unless needed.

If I'm able to get a correct DNS lookup for mymaindomain.com and my ssh keys are setup properly to let me login (and have been working for a year), what could suddenly cause this to happen? Why is sshing to my main domain causing me to hang?

EDIT: It was suggested I do `ssh -v` to see what's happening. Here is the output:

```
$ ssh -v kenny@mymaindomain.com
OpenSSH_7.6p1, LibreSSL 2.6.2
debug1: Reading configuration data /etc/ssh/ssh_config
debug1: /etc/ssh/ssh_config line 48: Applying options for *
debug1: Connecting to mymaindomain.com port 22.
```

and then it hangs.

EDIT 2: I changed the destination's sshd_config to set the logging level at `DEBUG3` which is the highest. When I try to `ssh kenny@mymaindomain.com` I get **absolutely nothing** in the log. When I `ssh kenny@xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx` then I'm successfully able to login and the log spews a TON of stuff.

I'm baffled.

Comment: Have you checked the ssh port, maybe it's just a firewall problem Try telnet mymaindomain.com 22

Comment: The two most likely explanations are that either the domain is pointing to an incorrect IP address or you created the VM with an ephemeral IP address rather than static, and the VM was restarted causing the ephemeral IP to change.

Comment: To find out what causes the delay, run `ssh -v`. And when you munge domain names, use `example.com`, `example.net` and so on.

Comment: @Talal Port 22 is not blocked, which you can see since I'm able to ssh in with the IP or another domain on the same server.

Comment: @kasperd The domain isn't pointing to the wrong IP address, that's why I did a `host` look up my main domain and the other domain. They both point to the same IP and the connection works with just the IP and works using the other domain, just not the main domain.

Comment: @KennyWyland The server is never told what domain name you are using. The `ssh -v` output is somewhat suspect. It's supposed to tell you which IP address it is connecting to, not a name. In order to explain that we'd need to know the contents of `/etc/ssh/ssh_config` and `~/.ssh/config`.

Comment: @kasperd I don't have an `~/.ssh/config` on my local iMac nor on my remote CentOS server. The contents of my iMac's ssh_config can be seen here: https://pastebin.com/VieCgsqB

Answer (score 0):

A friend suggested cranking up the sshd logging on the remote CentOS server, and I turned it up to `DEBUG3` and the server logged absolutely NOTHING when I tried to connect from my Mac. That made me realize that my attempt to ssh from my Mac is never even touching the remote server.

I tried pinging and no pings got through. But I was able to connect using Chrome and load one of the websites hosted on the server, so that told me that I was able to lookup and connect via the domain name. However, now I think I was misled by this data point that Chrome had perhaps cached the IP lookup from some point in the past and was able to use that.

I used homebrew to install telnet and tried to connect to mymaindomain.com port 22 and it hung... but then timed out and gave me an actual error message!

`nodename nor servname provided, or not known`

That error message led me to several pages suggested that MacOS X's internal DNS resolver might be the problem and [they suggested](https://stackoverflow.com/a/40754476/416631) `killall -HUP mDNSResponder`. That did not solve it.

[Others suggested](https://gist.github.com/mipmip/1844353) `launchctl unload -w /System/Library/LaunchDaemons/com.apple.mDNSResponder.plist` followed by  `launchctl load -w /System/Library/LaunchDaemons/com.apple.mDNSResponder.plist`

However, that refused to run and said: `Operation not permitted while System Integrity Protection is engaged`.

So, I figured the easiest way to reload Mac OS X's internal dns cache was to reboot. *sigh* and that worked. I fell victim to the classic error when I didn't just try turning it off and on again.